# Pointer of pointers: std:vector vs. Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

Quick question:

Is saying

```
#include <vector>
vector<Object*>* arr = new vector<Object*>();
```

a parallel-version/similar/etc to

```
Object** arr = new Object*[100]; //I guess any size can do since vector maximum size changes all the time.
```

?

And if I am wrong could someone correct me?

Comment: The first is a pointer to an "array", if you will, of pointers. The second is an "array" of pointers.

Comment: @chris So I suppose, that means my suspicions were right?

Comment: Well, the first is a pointer to X, and the second is X, where the Xs aren't exactly equal, but can represent the same thing. That extra pointer to in the first differentiates it.

Comment: @raina77ow the question is about whether the vector is a pointer of pointers just as the second example is.

Comment: The vector is a pointer of pointers, but you've added an extra unnecessary pointer to your vector example.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is:

```
vector<Object*> arr;
```

This will be an "array" of pointers. (the array will be automatically destroyed when you leave the scope that you declare it in).

Of course, you *can* have `vector<Object*>*`, but it is more similar to

```
Object*** arr = new Object**;
*arr = new Object*[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's more similarity between this

```
#include <vector>

vector<Object*> arr(100);
```

and this

```
Object** arr = new Object*[100];
```

Why do people feel the need to new everything all the time? I think because its complicated and therefore it must be good, right? Wrong actually.

Comment: I think the "need to new" is coming from the Java, where you call new for every object that you create.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the "parallelism" that you're looking for is between the following two definitions:

```
vector<Object*> arr;
Object** arr = new Object*[100];
```

The only way in which these are "parallel versions" of each other is that they both provide some sort of set or list of pointers to `Object`. They are both, in a sense, "arrays" of pointers to `Object` and you could access a member `x` of the objects like `arr[0]->x` with both. However, neither is *truly* of type `array of pointer to Object`.

In particular, the thing that makes your first definition different to the second is that you have a pointer to the `vector`. In that case you would access member `x` like `(*arr)[0]->x`, having to dereference the pointer first.

These two definitions of `arr` are very different to each other in many ways though, so I would never think of them as being similar. The first is more idiomatic C++ because the vector will sort out the allocation and deallocation of the pointers for you. With the second, you'll need to remember to call `delete[]` later on. The `vector` also gives you a dynamically sized container and many of the other awesome features that come as part of a `vector`.

However, neither is the best choice as far as writing clean and idiomatic C++ is concerned. Regardless of which choice you make, you're still going to have to allocate (with `new`) the actual `Object`s that you're going to store pointers to and then remember to `delete` them. Your best choice here is to just use a `vector<Object> arr`. If, for some reason, you really need to store pointers to the objects, then you're much better off using some kind of smart pointer, such as in `vector<shared_ptr<Object>> arr`. If your container is going to be of fixed size (like the array of size 100 in your example), then you might prefer to use `array<Object, 100>`.